# Is there any event that fires when any of my UI elements changes in WPF/C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, user-interface

I have a WPF app with lots of textboxes and comboboxes that make up the UI.  I have a 'Save' button that I want to turn red whenever any of those textboxes or comboboxes content changes.  Is there a single event that I can handle so that I don't have to write

```
btnSave.Foreground = Brushes.Red
```

for the _TextChanged event for every textbox?

Answer (score 3):

You could loop through all textboxes on the form by looping through the form's child `Controls`, and bind the event in one swoop accordingly.

```
//-- This is a hair on the pseudo side, ChangeSavebuttonToRedHandler is an event 
//-- handler for your foreground change.. You can also use a lambda or whatever 
//-- you'd like.
foreach(var loChild in this.Controls)
{
    if(loChild is TextBox)
    {
        loChild.TextChanged += ChangeSaveButtonToRedHandler;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty ways to do such a thing. The best thing is to understand `"Bubbling and Tunneling in WPF"` and the usage of `"Attached events"`. Here are some references:

This link has all you need.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx

http://www.wpfmentor.com/2008/11/understand-bubbling-and-tunnelling-in-5.html

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use Blend to create a behavior. See: [Adding Visibility Behaviors Using Blend to A DataGrid for WPF or Silverlight](http://omegacoder.com/?p=876)